# Error 53 when mounting Azure network drive

Tags: azure, cmd, fileshare

So, trying to mount a network drive on my local network via CMD low and behold, I get the error 53. I spoke to my ISP, they don't block any port 445's, so I went to unblock TCP port 445 from my Windows Defender Firewall Advanced Settings - as illustrated - and not surprisingly it still wouldn't have it.

Looking on the CMD Window, you can see that port 445 is still "Listening" and not "Established" like it should be.

I'm sorry but if I unblock a port then I expect it to be unblocked - I dont expect my system to develop a mind of it's own and decide to go against my wishes.

Any other ideas as to why this could be?

[Windows Firewall Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG542.png)

[CMD Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj1Of.png)

Comment: I want to mount the drive on the local computer. The drive is the H drive. It’s a simple copy and paste from the Azure portal of the CMD code to mount the drive to the “Drives and Devices” section under “This PC”

Answer (score 0):

Mounting the drive in the Azure VM is fine, it’s just my local PC it’s struggling with.

The stupid thing it I’ve done this before with no problems - so why this time does it not like it?